# Chrome Javascript console: missing phantom resource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resources, console

When using Chrome's JavaScript console I get this error:

```
X GET file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/ (...etc etc...) /479415
```

Normally that last part would be a missing GIF or JPG, but nothing is missing, and I cannot find any reference to "479415". The tools in FireFox and IE don't find anything wrong. I've stepped through the code line by line using breakpoints and F10, and this error just appears after index.html has loaded. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Does it happen on any other page? Do you have any plug-ins on chrome?

Comment: No plugins that I'm aware of, and only on that page. The only thing that happens on the page is an animated character moves across the screen: a div is created, and its background image and style values change. This involves a large amount of JavaScript running simultanously, so identifying the problem code is non-trivial!

Comment: Solved: for future reference, a function that expected an image as an argument received a number instead. The error was not shown until Chrome tried and failed to download it, hence the error did not appear until many lines after its cause.